# NuSoap - How to use local, existing WSDL file in nusoap_client PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I am new to nusoap, and web services in general.

The wsdl file comes from the client. I have a basic web service working with the default URL which supplies the wsdl via the web address: `http://hiddenurl.com/ws/schema/Terminal.wsdl`

But the client's documentation says:
"Please download the WSDL and XML schema files locally for your code to use. Do not get those files every time from our server."

So I have been trying to host the wsdl file locally, or via my own web server, but neither have worked.

I have tried:

```
$wsdlUrl = 'http://supplied-url.com/schema/Terminal.wsdl'    // working but discouraged

$wsdlUrl = 'http://my-own-IIS-based-url/schema/Terminal.wsdl'    // url loads and I can
  // view wsdl file, but when I load run webservice is returns blank / nothing 

$wsdlUrl = 'path/to/local/Terminal.wsdl'    // returns blank or 'boolean'false'

$tempUrl = realpath('path/to/local/Terminal.wsdl')    // get absolute url
wsdlUrl = tempUrl;    // returns blank screen or 'boolean'false'
```

Is there any way I can have the web service use the wsdl file from a location other than the one originally supplied by the client? I've seen some references to web servers returning wsdl with a sort of http://getfile.php?file.wsdl but I don't understand what would be in the 'getfile.php' in order to deliver the wsdl via the query string.

Here is my PHP code to call the web service. Again, it works with the client supplied URL for the wsdl file, but not when I try to access the wsdl file any other way.

```
<?php
require_once('nusoap.php');

$URI = 'http://api.hiddenurl.com/ws/schema';

$env = 'api'; 
$wsdlUrl = 'http://'.$env.'.hiddenurl.com/schema/Terminal.wsdl';
$licenseKey = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx';
$userName = 'user';
$password = 'password';

$service = new nusoap_client($wsdlUrl, true);

// login credentials
$service->setHeaders(
'<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://hiddenurl.xsd">'.
'<wsse:UsernameToken>'.
'<wsse:Username>'.$userName.'</wsse:Username>'.
'<wsse:Password Type="http://hiddenurl#PasswordText">'.$password.'</wsse:Password>'.
'</wsse:UsernameToken>'.
'</wsse:Security>'
);

$msg =
'<GetDetailsRequest xmlns="'.$URI .'">'.
'<messageId></messageId>'.
'<version></version>'.
'<licenseKey>'.$licenseKey.'</licenseKey>'.
'<iccids>'.
'<iccid>'.'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.'</iccid>'.
'</iccids>'.
'</GetDetailsRequest>';

$result = $service->call('GetlDetails', $msg);

if ($service->fault) {
  echo 'faultcode: ' . $service->faultcode . "\n";
  echo 'faultstring: ' . $service->faultstring . "\n";
  echo 'faultDetail: ' . $service->faultdetail . "\n";
  echo 'response: ' . $service->response;
  exit(0);
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: `path/to/local/Terminal.wsdl` should work - are you sure you're passing in the correct path? What's the return value of `file_exists('path/to/local/Terminal.wsdl')`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. `file_exists('path/to/local/Terminal.wsdl')` returns 1, of which I assume `1 == true`.

Comment: recent versions of php come with a native soap client (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php), if changing clients is a possibility I suggest trying the native client

Comment: Does `file_get_contents("path/to/local/Terminal.wsdl")` work for retrieving the file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$wsdl_location= realpath('path/to/local/Terminal.wsdl');
$wsdl_cache = new nusoap_wsdlcache("/tmp"); // for caching purposes
$wsdl_obj = $wsdl_cache->get($wsdl_location);
if (empty($wsdl_obj)) {
  $wsdl_obj=new wsdl($wsdl_location);
  $wsdl_cache->put($wsdl_obj);
}
$service = new nusoap_client($wsdl_obj,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using localhost path:

$wsdlUrl = 'http://localhost/schema/Terminal.wsdl';

p.s. This url will not work in browser but can be executed through php script on server.

Comment: Why would that be any different than `$wsdlUrl = 'http://my-own-IIS-based-url/schema/Terminal.wsdl'` which he already tried